# cleanup in useEffect when useState change not working

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am using fetch to fetch data as follow:

```
const [regstatus, setRegstatus] = useState("");
     useEffect(() => {
            
            fetch('url*********************')
    
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((res) => {
    
                    if (res.success === true) {
    
                        setRegstatus(res.status);
    
                    }
    
                })

 }, [regstatus]);
```

So I am using dependency  `[regstatus]` to cleanup once it changed however that doesn't work for me as in screen I am printing this  `regstatus` as showing below:

```
    {regstatus == "pending" ?

                    <View>
                     /* show something here */

                    </View>

                    : 
                        <View>
                     /* show something here */

                    </View>

                    }
```

So, here once `regstatus` changed, it is not execute related view in ternary conditions above as I need to close the app and open again to show the updates

Comment: before setRegstatus, what exactly you're getting in res.status? @anie

Comment: Btw, an effect will run any time one of its dependencies is updated, and this effect sets its own dependency. If `res.status` is an object, or changes every time, the effect will run on an infinite loop.

Comment: @LakshmanKambam i am getting the status name such as pending, on hold... etc, which string

Comment: @windowsill so you mean I have to set dependency  to `res.status`?